# Glimpse does not show requests that return a 303 See Other

Tags: redirect, nancy, glimpse

I've started to use Glimpse primarily to analyze the NHibernate queries, and so far everything works great for normal requests.

I'm using the [Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for the requests that change data. In Nancy, the web framework that I use, the default redirect type is 303 See Other. With that redirect, however, the POST request does not show up in the Glimpse history, so it is impossible to see the INSERT or UPDATE queries that the request generated.

If I change the response to 302 Found, everything works as expected. This is the approach I'm taking now, but I still wanted to ask:

Is this behavior a bug, or is it expected behavior in Glimpse?

I use the following versions of said libaries:

- Nancy 0.22.0 on ASP.NET 4.5
- Glimpse 1.8.2

Comment: Glimpse doesn't really work for Nancy at all... yet, it's too dependent on HttpContext, and until the dependency is properly broken its too hard to implement good Nancy support.

Comment: @Phill that's not true. Maybe some features do not work, but I use it primarily to inspect the SQL queries, and that works like a charm (using the NHibernate Glimpse plugin).

Comment: Hence why I said "hard to implement good Nancy support" - https://twitter.com/csainty/status/419842468331675648